# How to move a Powershell function on one computer to a script on another computer

Tags: powershell-3.0

I have a function that I use in my profile on my admin computer, that calls another script as part of it's process that queries a specific computers registry for a value:

```
function Get-ISMServiceState ($computername = "$env:computername", $Service)  {
$registryPath = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\....\ISM\Private\ApplicationData\$Service"
$State = (.\Get-RemoteRegistryKeyProperty $computername $registryPath State).State
Write-Host -foregroundcolor green "$Computername - $Service State is: $State"
}
```

the **Get-RemoteRegistryKeyProperty.ps1** script used by this function is stored in the same directory that I am running the function from at the commandline, so when I call the function at the commandline, with the 2 parameters **sta9int2** and **SMGateway**, I get the output I expect:

```
PS C:\Users\ingracarroll\Documents\Scripts> Get-ISMServiceState sta9int2 SMGateway
sta9int2 - SMGateway State is: 2
```

I have taken the function and converted it to a script **Get-ISMServiceState.ps1** which I have copied to another machine and also copied the **Get-RemoteRegistryKeyProperty.ps1** to the same directory.

```
param($computername, $Service)
$registryPath = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\....\ISM\Private\ApplicationData\$Service"
$State = (.\Get-RemoteRegistryKeyProperty $computername $registryPath State).State
Write-Host -foregroundcolor green "$Computername - $Service State is: $State"
```

If I run this script from my machine I get the expected output:

```
PS C:\Users\ingracarroll\Documents\Scripts> . \\sta9mon\c$\Data\Powershell\Get-ISMServiceState sta9int2 SMGateway
sta9int2 - SMGateway State is: 2
```

but if I run the same script on the other machine in the directory both scripts are stored in I get the following:

```
PS C:\data\powershell>  .\Get-ISMServiceState sta9int2 SMGateway
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\data\powershell\Get-RemoteRegistryKeyProperty.ps1:62 char:25
+ foreach($keyProperty in $key.GetValueNames())
+                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\data\powershell\Get-RemoteRegistryKeyProperty.ps1:77 char:1
+ $key.Close()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

sta9int2 - SMGateway State is:
```

So it would appear that my script running on this machine is not executing the following line correctly, even though it does when run remotely from my other machine:

```
$State = (.\Get-RemoteRegistryKeyProperty $computername $registryPath State).State
```

I'm sure this is just me doing something basic wrong but I can't see what it is.

Can anyone point out the error of my ways?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, after continued investigation into my issue here I have found that the main point where the script is failing, is when it is trying to query the registry entry.

This is due to a difference in platforms, my admin machine is a 32bit Windows 7 Platform, the machine I need to run this script from is a 64bit Windows Server 2008 R2 Platform.

On the 32bit machine the code below works fine for reading the registry key identified:

```
$registryPath = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\....\ISM\Private\ApplicationData\$Service"
```

Running from a 32bit platform I can read the registry of either the 32bit or 64bit platforms with the above.

On the 64bit machine the code needs to be changed to include the Wow6432Node section to read the same registry key identified, on 64bit platforms:

```
$registryPath = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\....\ISM\Private\ApplicationData\$Service"
```

Additionally I changed the call to the external script to:

```
$State = (. c:\data\powershell\Get-RemoteRegistryKeyProperty $computername $registryPath State).State
```

so that this can be run via batch script when started using the these parameters:

```
PowerShell.exe -NonInteractive -NoProfile -file "Get-ISMServiceState.ps1" %1 %2
```

Hope this may help some oters who may have been struggling with any similiar situation.